# How do I display information in a foreach loop differently depending on the parent node's doc type?

Tags: loops, umbraco, nodes, doctype, umbraco7

So I've got a foreach loop that currently displays a list of nodes, and then a nested list of nodes under that. I would like to expand it a little so that the nested list looks differently depending on what doctype its parent node has.

Here's the hierarchy of what I'm working with:

- Directory (doctype is Directory Landing)
- - Players (doctype is Player Folder)
- - - Tolkien
- - - Lewis
- - Current Characters (doctype is Player Character Folder)
- - - Katniss
- - NPCs (doctype is NPC folder)
- - - Lando
- - Past Characters (doctype is Past Character Folder)
- - - Elrond
- - - Aslan

So I want an if statement, I think, to basically ask "if the parent is Player Folder, display Name and Picture of each node beneath it, if it's Character Folder, display Name and Picture and Summary, if it's anything else, just display the name"). The problem is I don't know how to make it check for what doctype it is.

Here's the code I have so far:

```
<section id="directoryListing">
<ul>
    @{
        var LogsNode = Model.Content.AncestorOrSelf("DirectoryLanding");
    }
    @foreach (var node in LogsNode.Children.Where("Visible"))
    {
        <li>
            <h2>@node.AsDynamic().Name</h2>
            <ul>
                @foreach (var childnode in node.Children)
                {
                    <!-- If statement would presumably begin here -->
                    <li><!-- each section of the If statement would contain something like this-->
                        <a href="@childnode.Url">@childnode.Name</a>
                    </li>
                    <!-- If statement would presumably end here -->
                }
            </ul>
        </li>
    }
</ul>
</section>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this:

```
<section id="directoryListing">
<ul>
    @{
        var LogsNode = Model.Content.AncestorOrSelf("DirectoryLanding");

        foreach (var node in LogsNode.Children.Where("Visible"))
        {
            <li>
                <h2>@node.Name</h2>
                <ul>
                    @foreach (var childnode in node.Children)
                    {
                        if (childnode.Parent.DocumentTypeAlias == "Character")
                        {
                            <li>
                                <a href="@childnode.Url">@childnode.Name</a>
                            </li>
                        }
                        else if (childnode.Parent.DocumentTypeAlias == "Player")
                        {
                            <li>
                                <a href="@childnode.Url">@childnode.Name</a>
                            </li>
                        }
                    }
                </ul>
            </li>
        }
    }
</ul>
</section>
```

Answer (score 2):

There should be a DocumentTypeAlias property or NodeTypeAlias for the dynamic version.

You can check the cool cheat sheet here (works for v7 too):

https://our.umbraco.org/projects/developer-tools/umbraco-v6-mvc-razor-cheatsheets